# Convert C# razor to vb.net razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i am struggling with some C# razor code which i cannot handle to convert on vb.net can anyone of you help me out with that?:

Here's that code:

```
@{
    var alerts = TempData.ContainsKey(Alert.TempDataKey)
                ? (List<Alert>)TempData[Alert.TempDataKey]
                : new List<Alert>();

    if (alerts.Any())
    {
        <hr/>
    }

    foreach (var alert in alerts)
    {
        var dismissableClass = alert.Dismissable ? "alert-dismissable" : null;
        <div class="alert alert-@alert.AlertStyle @dismissableClass">
            @if (alert.Dismissable)
            {
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            }
            @Html.Raw(alert.Message)
        </div>
    }
}
```

**EDITED:**
Still something wrong, can you check?:

```
@code

    Dim alerts = If(TempData.ContainsKey(Alert.TempDataKey), DirectCast(TempData(Alert.TempDataKey), List(Of Alert)), New List(Of Alert)())

       @If alerts.Any() Then
        @<hr />
        End If

        @For Each item In alerts

            Dim dismissableClass = If(alert.Dismissable, "alert-dismissable", Nothing)
        @<div class="alert alert-@alert.AlertStyle @dismissableClass">
            @If (alert.Dismissable) Then

                @<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            End If
                @Html.Raw(alert.Message)
        </div>
        Next

end code
```

Comment: Try to find  online code converter

Comment: This line under `@<hr />     End if` needs to get changed to `End If`

Comment: see my EDIT again, now i have two problems in this line:  @For Each item In alerts  (item is not declared) and  Dim alerts = If(TempData.ContainsKey(Alert.TempDataKey), DirectCast(TempData(Alert.TempDataKey), List(Of Alert)), New List(Of Alert)())    - here variable declarations for alert without as ... also Alert is unknown...why? I have this class in my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will have to convert all `if` statements to `If-EndIF`

Example:

```
@If price>30 Then
    @<p>The price is too high.</p>
End If

replace @{ --- } with @code --- EndCode


and replace the expression as below converted

Dim alerts = If(TempData.ContainsKey(Alert.TempDataKey), DirectCast(TempData(Alert.TempDataKey), List(Of Alert)), New List(Of Alert)())

Dim dismissableClass = If(alert.Dismissable, "alert-dismissable", Nothing)

Html.Raw(alert.Message)
```

Comment: @maxshuty  can you please check my main post ? There is still something wrong, can youu check?

Comment: @maxshuty can you also take a look on my comment :)